# Page is not loading(No html body) for extracting data in Scapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

I have used Scrapy 1.5.0 for crawling products in a website during crawling it showed me 302 redirecting issue but doesn't crawl the data for some of the pages.

```
Redirecting (302) to <GET www.xyz.com>
```

So, I have used **scrapy-splash** and it solved the issue of **"redirecting 302"**. But now the same pages are not loading and the Response which I am getting for that page is

```
<Selector xpath=None data='<html class="a-no-js" lang="en-us"><!--<'>
```

If the page is correctly loaded then this is the response for that page

```
<Selector xpath=None data='<html class=" a-js a-audio a-video a-can'>
```

And if I gave wait of 10 seconds then all the pages are crawled. So is there any way to solve this issue without using wait. This is the syntax for Request

```
yield SplashRequest(response.urljoin(result), callback=self.parse_page, args={'wait': 10}, endpoint = 'render.html',)
```

Comment: Couple of questions: (1) What's wrong with redirect itself? (2) What's the issue with `wait`? Are you concerned with speed or anythign else?

Comment: (1) It just redirects to the page and doesn't crawl any data.
(2) I am very much concern about speed and using `wait` would decrease the speed.